# First name disambiguation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I've been handed a project that I'm trying to find a premise for. Essentially I am going to be taking customer information from a number of transactional databases. Then merging them into one dimension table with various interesting information from all the records. Some of these people may be in many of the databases or multiple times in the same database or both.

Since the name comes from user input one entry may say Sally Jones, one may say Susan Jones, one may say S Jones and it all still be the same person. The way I'm THINKING of going about this is finding disambiguations of as many names as I can and putting it into a bridge table so when I pull new info from a transaction database I can run it through the bridge table and match it do any of the names that are listed

Has anyone done or heard of something similar? Or know of a table/list that can can import into excel/sql that will give me a starting point for first name disambiguations?

Comment: If you have not done so already, look through the following discussion: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/778986.html

Comment: You can use [Data Quality Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877917.aspx)

Comment: If you assume that all records with idenitical first and last names automatically mean it's the same person, you might not be correct.

Comment: Correct, the 'Same person' factor is going to be calculated as a weighted ranking, via a combination of personal factors. So in order for a 'match' to be achieved the ranking has to be beyond a certain threshold. So there will be 3 levels if you will, a HIGH certainty where a proc will automatically update the table based on this and trigger a flag, a MODERATE certainty where it won't make a change and get dumped inter a separate table, and a low/no certainty where nothing happens to it and it just treats it as a new person. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Another problem you'll probably face during your data cleansing process are occurences where the name is spelled differently but the person behind it is the same. For such cases there is the SQL function `soundex()`. Yet, a lot of people are a bit disgrunted with the search-and-match algorithm and therefore wrote their own. You might want to look into that problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a Clients table and a a way to associate this table with the Transactions table. If the clients table doesn't exists in the DB, I advise you to create it to make your task possible. It's extremely important to have a single identification for each client and connect clients with transactions to know exactly all the transactions per client.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do (create a customers table), the question was a way of disambiguating the same customer so we can with a high level of certainty say that this person who someone put in as S Jones is the same person as Sally Jones - to refer back to my example. I found a number of name to nickname databases that will serve for now, but it doesn't really help with names that are outside of the english language. Also trying to user a variety of matching criteria. Like E-Mail, Phone Number, Address, DL# and assigning weights to each to give me a % of certainty.